# Can I prove I'm not cheating?

Tags: paladins

Three days ago, I was banned in Paladins: Champions of the Realm. I get reported with some frequency after matches due to hacking accusations, probably because I have decent aim and understanding of the game. One week ago, a twitch streamer told his viewers to report me — but I never expected I'd actually be banned from the game because of that.

I've already sent an email to Hi-Rez (the developer) requesting a review of my ban, and told them about the streamer. They haven't answered me since then, but I'm wondering if there's a way to prove I was not hacking/cheating? How?

If not, is there anything I can do other than sit and cry if they decide not to change my situation?

Comment: @Vemonus you removed the `cheats` tag so I'll ask it to you: Is there a tag I can use to mark this question as being `game-agnostic`?

Comment: no, there really isn't any other tag necessary for this question

Comment: @Vemonus understandable but this question is not specially tied to Paladins, anyway thanks for your help. I'm probably too used to other stackexchange sites.

Comment: @TiagoMarinho saw your Reddit thread and I'm glad you got unbanned, I cannot stand people who witch hunt on players like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try to reach Paladins employees on [Paladins Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Paladins/) or [Paladins Official Forum](http://forums.paladins.com/).

If you can provide strong evidences that you are not a cheater (like the video where the streamer asked to report you, or your paladins guru profile to show that your skills are real) the community should support you and help you be seen by Hirez Employees.

Here is an example of [what OP posted on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Paladins/comments/6ca8r7/how_hirez_handles_hacking_accusations/) which helped him getting unbanned.

Answer (score 4):

The first step would be to contest the ban. When you make your case, provide as much evidence as possible, most importantly video or picture evidence, such as the clip of the stream you mentioned where they called you out to be reported. The second step is to just wait, and if you really need to, you can always make a second steam account.

Comment: Since I wasted money in that account and A LOT of time (lv121 currently), I'd like to avoid to use the last option even if it meant involving a lawyer. Thanks for the answer, I'll probably include as much information as possible when contesting.

Comment: @Tiago If you can find a recording of the stream where the streamer says to report you, it will likely help quite a bit.  Assuming you told them about that already, I think there's a chance it works out (I don't know how good Hi-Rez CS is).  They would notice if you got mass reported by people you didn't even play against.

Answer (score 4):

It's very difficult to prove innocence in hacker accusations. They are essentially witch hunts. Most of the time hacks are detected and just banned on the spot there, but when player reports come in... it's their word vs yours. If they have a large number of reports against you, there's not much you can do to defend yourself.

All is not lost, though! If I remember correctly, Paladins does have a spectator mode that you can plug match IDs into and spectate various aspects. Find the MatchID of this game the streamer claimed you were hacking in, and send that to Hi-Rez as evidence. Using just the streamer's video may not help as it will likely only show their side of things.

Comment: "Using just the streamer's video may not help as it will likely only show their side of things." If anything, this is what you would want.  Seeing it from their perspective would help Hi-Rez tell what the opponent saw to decide "hacks".  Unless there was infallible evidence that it was definitely cheats; HR staff would probably be able to tell it was just someone raging.  If the footage isn't good enough to _prove_ cheating, and the HR anti-cheat logs aren't conclusive; I don't see why they would maintain the ban.  They may also become more skeptical of the streamer.

Comment: Any information regarding how to proceed if the ticket failed? Should I contact a lawyer? Because that just happened.

Comment: @TiagoMarinho If you're willing to pay for a lawyer and everything to deal with this, that's up to you. As I said, it's your word vs the streamer's unless you provide solid proof. Hi-Rez is not known for benefit of the doubt.

Comment: @TiagoMarinho If you have some proof you can try posting on [paladins reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Paladins/) and [paladins forum](http://forums.paladins.com/forum.php). There are some paladins employees there who might help you.

Comment: @Lordofdark what's fun about your comment is that, one day before you wrote it, I posted [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Paladins/comments/6ca8r7/how_hirez_handles_hacking_accusations/?st=j33jigiq&sh=8b73149f) in the paladins subreddit. It has become the most famous post from the entire subreddit, earning me 1750 upvotes in three days. I  also got my account unbanned very quickly.

Comment: @TiagoMarinho Nice welcome back than :) I had not seen your post, I don't go that much on reddit

Comment: @Lordofdark feel free to post your comment as an answer and I'll mark it as the correct one, since it's the closest thing in this question to what helped me.